# Global Variable for file name

Tags: c++, global-variables

Say for example i have this line of code in 4 parts of my program file main.cpp

`ifstream fin; fin.open("filename.txt")`

But i dont want to go and change all these filenames in all these four locations.

How could i make a global variable name for this? Does it work different with filenames.txt ?

Comment: 4 location in a one file or a few?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you tried a global variable like this:

```
const std::string filename = "filename.txt";
```

and then tried to initialize the `ifstream` with:

```
ifstream fin; fin.open(filename);
```

and it didn't work for you. This may be because you do not have a C++ compiler or library that supports the 2011 standard. If you did have such a compiler, it would work fine. However, if you do not, you will need to pass a C style string to the `ifstream` constructor.

```
ifstream fin; fin.open(filename.c_str());
```

Comment: Worked perfect. Just tried it out! I wasnt sure that using a const would work the same way for a filename.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would go about it.

Pass a command line arguments specifying the path of your application config file. When your application loads it parses this config file and saves all the values for items such as filenames. Have a class, or a global structure that stores and delivers these values on request. Eg:

```
fin.open(AppConfig.get("filename")); // if the AppConfig is a class.
fin.open(AppConfig["filename"]); // if AppConfig was a map like structure.
```

This sort of Data Driven development is good practise. If its only one file you're using, you may simply want to define a constant name at the beginning of the file:

```
const char* FILENAME = "my file.txt"; // or
#define FILENAME "my file.txt"
```

And use the constant each time:

```
fin.open(FILENAME); // use this repeatedly
```

Comment: Now that is a good solution. Simple answer but a better option to aim for. +1

Comment: Please don't go with the #define. They so very mess things up when it's so very unnecessary.

Comment: I don't recommend it, but it's still valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a global const variable

```
const char* fileName = "filename.txt";
```

or

```
const std::string fileName = "filename.txt";
```

Global variable are not bad if they cannot mutate. Then usage:

```
ifstream fin(fileName);
```

Comment: Even better solution, which doesn't create an extra pointer: `const char filename[] = "filename.txt";`